# How can I remove the repeat character in row?

Tags: python, pandas

here is my dataframe

```
year
|0|0|0|0|2010|0|0|2018
|0|0|2017|0|0|2019
```

I have try this code but it is not working for me

```
df['year'] = df['year'].str.replace('|0|', ',')
```

I would like to see the result like this

```
    year
    2010, 2018
    2017, 2019
```

any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest extract all digits with length `4` by [`Series.str.findall`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.findall.html) and then join by `,` by [`Series.str.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.join.html) :

```
df['year'] = df['year'].str.findall('\d{4}').str.join(', ')
print (df)
         year
0  2010, 2018
1  2017, 2019
```

Another solution if need remove `0` values:

```
df['year'] = [', '.join(y for y in x.strip('|').split('|') if y != '0') for x in df['year']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Storing numeric data as comma-separated string in a Pandas series is anti-pattern. You forfeit any possibility of vectorised computations. If viable for your use case, extract integers and add multiple *numeric* series:

```
# input dataframe
# df = pd.DataFrame({'year': ['|0|0|0|0|2010|0|0|2018', '|0|0|2017|0|0|2019']})

L = [list(filter(None, map(int, x.strip('|').split('|')))) for x in df['year']]
df = df.join(pd.DataFrame(pd.Series(L).values.tolist()))

print(df)
#                      year     0     1
# 0  |0|0|0|0|2010|0|0|2018  2010  2018
# 1      |0|0|2017|0|0|2019  2017  2019
```

Note the `filter(None, ...)` idiom is used to remove Falsy values, including `0`.